# Return async function to express router

Tags: node.js, express

This may sound dum. But what I am stuck here with is

1: returning the converted JSON file
2: getting the returned object into the route

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const routings = require('./src/services/routings');

router.get('/routings', async(req, res) => {
    const routesRes = await routings.getRoutings();
    res.end(JSON.stringify(routesRes, null, " ")).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

routings.js

```
const parseXml = require('xml2js')

let data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...'

getRoutings = async() => {
    await parseXml.parseStringPromise(data).then(function (result) {
        console.log('Done');
        return result;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {getRoutings}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getRoutings()` function does not have a return value.   Therefore when you do this:

```
const routesRes = await routings.getRoutings();
```

`routesRes` will always be `undefined`.

I would suggest this:

```
getRoutings = () => {
    return parseXml.parseStringPromise(data).then(function (result) {
        console.log('Done');
        return result;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;          // make sure error is propagated
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks @jfriend00 for one word i have been struggling for hours 